# Calling jQuery plugin with function to run in plugin

Tags: jquery

```
$.fn.example = function( ) {
  $.getJSON("example.json", function(json){ 
    //1
  });
};

$("div").example(function () {
  $(this).text(json.text); //2
});
```

I want to do something like this. #2 must run in #1.

Answer (score 1):

So define a variable in the arguments and use it?

```
$.fn.example = function( callback ) {
    var cb = callback ? $.proxy(callback, this) : function(){};
    var txt = $(this).text().toUpperCase();
    $.getJSON("example.json", function(json){  
        cb(json);
    });
};

$("div").example(function (json) {
    $(this).text(json.text); //2
});
```

http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#accepting-options

Comment: I edited it, this is not the normal pattern of a plugin.

Comment: Browser console:
ReferenceError: json is not defined

Comment: Did you add all of the references to json?

Comment: JSON works fine with directly getJSON function. I think browser can't fine json function.

Comment: I tried complately same with your code. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're using the [jquery_example](https://github.com/mudge/jquery_example) plugin.

Based on your code, the example text you want is located in `json.text`. In that case you can just initialize it inside the callback function:

```
$.fn.example = function( ) {
    $.getJSON("example.json", function(json){ 
        $("div").example(json.text);
    });
};
```